# Google Apps Script silently running portions of my onEdit script twice

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I've got the following Google Apps Script code which is triggered by an edit to a cell that has a dropdown data validation (Pick from List) on it.  Occasionally it adds two duplicate rows to the target table instead of the desired single row.  I've added Logging in a variety of locations to see if I can detect when/where/why some piece of code is running twice. The logs don't show any sections of the script running unexpectedly.  I've added Locking as well.  It didn't help with this issue, although it did make the script run in a more reliable fashion. I really want to get to the bottom of this although it is really just a nuisance at this point.  Please let me know if you need any additional info:

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  Logger.log('Running onEdit');
  var lock = LockService.getUserLock();
  lock.waitLock(10000);
  var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.columnStart;
  var row = range.rowStart;
  var status = range.getDisplayValue();
  if (col == 7 && row >= 13 && row <= 53) {  //Ongoing Block
    cache.put("oldStatus", e.oldValue);
    Logger.log(row,col,status, e.oldValue);
    if (status == 'ToVendor') {  //Send to Vendor Block
      copyEquipRow(spreadsheet,row,col,1,true);
      Logger.log(row,col,cache.get("equipID"),cache.get("dateAdded"),cache.get("priority"),cache.get("problem"),cache.get("location"),cache.get("targetDate"));
      pasteToVendor(spreadsheet);
    }
    if (status == 'AddReq') {   //Add Related Req to the Req Block
      copyEquipRow(spreadsheet,row,col,1,false);
      Logger.log(row,col,cache.get("equipID"),cache.get("dateAdded"),cache.get("priority"),cache.get("problem"),cache.get("location"),cache.get("targetDate"));
      addReq(spreadsheet);
      spreadsheet.getRange(row, col).setValue(e.oldValue)
    }
  }
  if (col == 16 && row >= 31 && row <= 37) {  //Vendor Block
    cache.put("oldStatus", e.oldValue);
    Logger.log(row,col,status, e.oldValue);
    if (status == 'ToOngoing') {
      copyEquipRow(spreadsheet,row,col,0,true);
      Logger.log(row,col,cache.get("equipID"),cache.get("dateAdded"),cache.get("priority"),cache.get("problem"),cache.get("location"),cache.get("targetDate"));
      pasteToOngoing(spreadsheet);
    }
  }
  lock.releaseLock();
}

function copyEquipRow(spreadsheet,row,col,problemCol,deleteRow) {   //Status    Equip # Date Added  Priority    Problem     Location    Target Date
  Logger.log('Running CopyEquipRow');
  var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();
  var locationCol = 5 + problemCol;
  var targetCol = 6 + problemCol;
  var clearCol = 7 + problemCol;
  var dateAdded = Utilities.formatDate(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 2).getValue(), "EST", "M/d/yyyy");
  var targetDate = Utilities.formatDate(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, targetCol).getValue(), "EST", "M/d/yyyy");
  cache.put("equipID", spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).getValue());
  cache.put("dateAdded",dateAdded);
  cache.put("priority",spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 3).getValue());
  cache.put("problem",spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 4).getValue());
  cache.put("location",spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, locationCol).getValue());
  cache.put("targetDate",targetDate);
  if (deleteRow == true ) {
    spreadsheet.getRange(row, col, 1, clearCol).clearContent();
  }
}

function pasteRow(spreadsheet,startCell,problemCol,includeStatus,dateOverride) {
  Logger.log('Running pasteRow');
  var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getRange(startCell).activate();
  var row = 0;
  while (currentCell.offset(row, 1).isBlank() == false) {
    row = ++row;
  }
  var oldStatus = cache.get("oldStatus");
  var equipID = cache.get("equipID");
  var dateAdded = cache.get("dateAdded");
  var priority = cache.get("priority");
  var problem = cache.get("problem");
  var location = cache.get("location");
  var targetDate = cache.get("targetDate");
  var locationcol = 5 + problemCol;
  var targetcol = 6 + problemCol;
  Logger.log(equipID,dateAdded,priority,problem,location,targetDate);
  if (includeStatus == true) {
    currentCell.offset(row, 0).setValue(oldStatus);
  }
  currentCell.offset(row, 1).setValue(equipID);
  if (dateOverride == true ){
    currentCell.offset(row, 2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "M/d/yyyy"));
  } 
  else {
    currentCell.offset(row, 2).setValue(dateAdded);
  }
  currentCell.offset(row, 3).setValue(priority);
  currentCell.offset(row, 4).setValue(problem);
  currentCell.offset(row, locationcol).setValue(location);
  currentCell.offset(row, targetcol).setValue(targetDate);
}

function pasteToVendor(spreadsheet) {
  Logger.log('Running pasteToVendor');
  pasteRow(spreadsheet,'P30',0,true);
}

function pasteToOngoing(spreadsheet) {
  Logger.log('Running pasteToOngoing');
  pasteRow(spreadsheet,'G12',1,true);
}

function addReq(spreadsheet) {
  Logger.log('Running addReq');
  pasteRow(spreadsheet,'O12',1,false,true);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you created an installable trigger for your onEdit() function?

Comment: If you have then you should rename that function to something other than onEdit() and remove the onEdit.  You may be getting both the installable trigger and the simple trigger at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onEdit(e) function responds to the simple trigger which cannot perform operations that require permission.

The instable  onEdit trigger is tied to a function of you choice and it gets the same event object as the simple trigger.  If you don't rename the installable trigger to something other than onEdit() then you're definitely getting two triggers all of the  time.

Also keep in mind onEdit triggered functions must complete within 30 seconds.

[Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

[installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

[Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Comment: Great information.  not sure why I couldn't find such a simple answer somewhere online.   Why wasn't a seeing duplicate runs in the logs?  Are the simple trigger logs kept somewhere else?

Comment: They're both just triggers.  But in your case because your function is named onEdit() then your function is receiving both of them.  Just change the name and eliminated the one named onEdit and the simple trigger will continue to fire on edits however it won't go to your function any longer.